# Calculating Beta Binomial likelihood with n>1000

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, sympy

I'm struggling with a numerical precision issue in calculating the beta binomial likelihood.  My goal is to estimate the probability y mod 10 = d for some digit d,  given that y is Binomial(n,p) and p is Beta(a,b).  I'm trying to come up with a fast solution for large n, by which I mean at least 1000.  One thing that seems to be giving me reasonable answers is to use simulation.

```
def npliketest_exact(n,digit,a,b):
    #draw 1000 values of p 
    probs = np.array(beta.rvs(a,b,size=1000))
    #create an array of numbers whose last digit is digit 
    digits = np.arange(digit,n+1,10)
    #create a function that calculates the pmf at x given p
    exact_func = lambda x,p: binom(n,p).pmf(x)
    #given p, the likeklihood of last digit "digit" is the sum over all entries in digits
    likelihood = lambda p: exact_func(digits,p).sum()
    #return the average of that likelihood over all the draws
    return np.vectorize(likelihood)(probs).mean()

np.random.seed(1)
print npliketest_exact(1000,9,1,1) #0.0992310195195
```

This might be ok, but I'm worried about the precision of this strategy. In particular if there's a better/more precise way to do this calculation I'm eager to figure out how to do it.

I've started trying to use the log likelihood to come up with that answer, but I'm running into numerical stability issues even with that.

```
def llike(n,k,a,b):
    out = gammaln(n+1) + gammaln(k+a) + gammaln(n-k+b) + gammaln(a+b) - \
            ( gammaln(k+1) + gammaln(n-k+1) + gammaln(a) + gammaln(b) + gammaln(n+a+b) )
    return out

 print exp(llike(1000,9,1,1)) #.000999000999001
 print exp(llike(1000,500,1,1)) #.000999000999001
```

Since the beta 1,1 has mean 0.5, the probability of getting y=500 from a beta binomial with n=1000 should be much higher than getting 9, but the above calculations show a suspicious constant value.

Another thing I tried, which was suggested elsewhere on stackoverflow to deal with this problem, was to use some clever tricks to support numerical stability that are apparently hidden in scipy's betaln formula.

```
def binomln(n, k): #log of the binomial coefficient 
    # Assumes binom(n, k) >= 0
    return -betaln(1 + n - k, 1 + k) - log(n + 1)

def log_betabinom_exact(n,k,a,b):
    return binomln(n,k) + betaln(k+a,n-k+b) - betaln(a,b)

print exp(log_betabinom_exact(1000,9,1,1)) #.000999000999001
print exp(log_betabinom_exact(1000,500,1,1)) #0.000999000999001
```

Again, same suspicious constants. Would appreciate any advice.  Would using sympy be of any help on this?

**** Followup

Sorry guys, dumb mistake on my part, Beta(1,1) is uniform so the results I was getting make sense.  Trying different parameters makes things look differnet for different values of k.

Comment: Meaning of `gammaln(n+1) - gammaln(betaln(k+a,n-k+b) - beta(a,b))` ?

Comment: sorry, that's junk, let me edit that out

Comment: ok, I just started looking. If you find something, gimme a call...